# memory corruption when manipulating a long string

Tags: c, memory-corruption

I am writing a program to print out any line input that is longer than 3.

It works for some fairly long input lines, but for the string that is too long, I got a error message of memory corruption

```
*** Error in `./print-80': malloc(): memory corruption (fast): 0x00000000022ff030 ***
```

I don't know where the error is from. Can anyone explain me why there is the error and how to fix it?
Below is the program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LIMIT 3
#define LEAST_LENGTH 3

//function prototype
void copy(char* from, char* to);
int getline(char* s, int capacity);
int increase_capacity(char* s, int capacity);

int main(void) 
{
    int length, i;
    char* line = calloc(LIMIT, sizeof(char));

    while ((length = getline(line, LIMIT)) > 0)
    {
        if (length > LEAST_LENGTH)
            printf("Output: %s\n", line);

        //reset the line
        for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
            *(line + i) = 0;
    }

    free(line);
    return 0;
}

int getline(char* line, int capacity) 
{
    int c, length;

    length = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
    {
        if (length > (capacity - 1))
        {
            capacity = increase_capacity(line, capacity);
            printf("Address of line after increasing cap: %p\n", line);
        }

        line[length++] = c;
    }

    if (c == '\n')
        line[length++] = '\0';

    return length;
}

int increase_capacity(char* s, int capacity) 
{
    int i;
    capacity *= 2;
    char *new_s = calloc(capacity, sizeof(char));

    copy(s, new_s);
    s = new_s;

    free(new_s);
    return capacity;
}

void copy(char* from, char* to) 
{
    int i = 0;
    while ((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0')
        ++i;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to use a *debugger*?

Comment: Oh dear. There's a lot going on here but I think that with some basic clarification of the concept you can sort it out. There is some confusion about the pointer values (ie, addresses of memory stored in a `char *`) and actually allocated memory. You need to keep track of memory that you `calloc` and `free` *that* memory when you're done, and then not use it again.

Answer (score 2):

Your `increase_capacity` function can change the address at which the data is stored. But it doesn't return this information to its caller. So `getline` will write to the old buffer address. Similarly, `main` has no way to get the new address, so it will access the old address and `free` a block that may already be freed.

Also, your `increase_capacity` function allocates memory to hold the data and then frees that memory. That leaves no place to hold the data!

```
int increase_capacity(char* s, int capacity) 
 {
    int i;
    capacity *= 2;
    char *new_s = calloc(capacity, sizeof(char)); // allocate a larger block

    copy(s, new_s); // copy the data into the larger block
    s = new_s; // stash a pointer to the larger block in a local

    free(new_s); // free the block?!
    return capacity;
 }
```

So we allocate a new block, copy the data into it, and then free it. That makes no sense, we need to keep the larger block since that's the whole point of a function to increase capacity. We also don't return the address of the new block, so even if we didn't free it, no other code could access it and we'd just wind up leaking it. Double oops.

I suggest you create a `struct` that holds both the pointer to the block and its size. Pass a pointer to that `struct` to functions like `increase_capacity` so it can modify the pointer and the size in the structure and callers can see the changes.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the stupid mistake of freeing the new allocated block and suggesting the alternative. I will implement struct into the program